# caching a simple Username to UserId mapping to ease on the db

Tags: c#, database

hey,
I have a c# server-side app that has db (mysql), and quite oftenly, due to my DB current schema, i have to retrieve a user's id by his username in order to manipulate the user's data (such as editing his profile db tables etc.) .

I was thinking of creating a simple cache class that when it handles a request for a specific `username to userid` mapping, it caches the result in a dictionary,  or even in a dedicated dictionary for the first character of the given username.

Here is an example of what i was thinking:

```
public class UsernameToIdCache
{
    public int GetUserIdFromUsername(string username)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) return -1;

        var targetDictionary = _cacheDictionaries[username[0]];
        int id;
        if (targetDictionary.TryGetValue(username,out id))
        {
            return id;
        }
        else
        {
            id = RunSqlQuery("select id from users where username ='" + username + "'");
            if (IsDictionaryNotFull(targetDictionary))
            {
                targetDictionary.Add(username,id);
                return id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the `IsDictionaryNotFull(Dictionary<int,string>)` method is used for memory management (i don't want the dictionaries to explode, so it can only help until the dictionaries are full) .

what do you think? 
Is it a good db coding practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it ASP.NET app? If so, consider putting ID into Session object. It will be loaded once the user logs in and no other magic cacheing is needed.

Comment: +1 I totally agree. It seems like @programmer is over-complicating the issue.

Comment: But we don't know that. If he's developping a WebService he must do cacheing since WS are stateless.
If he's developping a socket-based server he can manually write UserContext class in which ID can be stored for the time of the connection.

Comment: No, Wcf. i'll update the question.Is there anything similar in wcf?

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful?
http://netindonesia.net/blogs/kasim.wirama/archive/2007/12/10/managing-state-in-wcf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The idea of caching is a good idea, especially if the volume of transactions is very high.  The key piece here is to remember that ASP.NET applications are multi-threaded, so you will want to be locking access to that dictionary when  you do the writes, as you don't want two threads trying to write the same data into the dictionary.

But overall I'd say if you need/want the performance gain of caching, then go for it.

Comment: It's going to be a WCF Service.